# xslt: i need sort by number

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have a problem to sort, when I sort by any attribute by text everything works correctly, but I want to sort the Amount attribute by number and I can not do it.

XML:

```
<REGISTERS ORDER="AMOUNT" TIPEORDER="ASC" PAG="1" LPP="100">
    <DEFREGISTERS>
        <COLUMN NAME="AMOUNT" DESC="Amount" FORMAT="NUMBER" TIPEDATA="NUMBER"/>
    </DEFREGISTERS>
    <REG>
        <DESCRIPTION DATA="FARM. VILLE" />
        <AMOUNT DATA="EX$110.00" FORMAT="NUMBER" />
    </REG>
    <REG>
        <DESCRIPTION DATA="FARM. VILLE 2" />
        <AMOUNT DATA="EX$210.00" FORMAT="NUMBER" />
    </REG>
    <REG>
        <DESCRIPTION DATA="FARM. VILLE 3" />
        <AMOUNT DATA="EX$310.00" FORMAT="NUMBER" />
    </REG>
    <REG>
        <DESCRIPTION DATA="FARM. BILL" />
        <AMOUNT DATA="EX$150.00" FORMAT="NUMBER" />
    </REG>
</REGISTERS>
```

My "Amount" attribute has characters and numbers, I want it to be sorted by number, and tried only to take the characters with a substring from the fourth character and I did not run it.

XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="REGISTERS/REG">
    <xsl:sort case-order="lower-first" select="./AMOUNT/@DATA" order="descending" data-type="number" />
    <xsl:if test="position() > 0 and position() < 101">
        <xsl:variable name="Row" select="4 - ((position() mod 2 * 2) + 1)" />
            <tr valign="middle" class="md-maketable-reg-tr">            
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tried only to take the characters with a substring from the fourth
>   character and I did not run it.

It works for me:

```
<xsl:sort select="substring(AMOUNT/@DATA, 4)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
```

Of course, this is assuming all amounts have a 3-char prefix.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it still does not work, it should be for the type of variable, since by text (data-type= "text") if it is ordered. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You'll have to explain yourself more clearly, I'm afraid I don't understand that sentence at all.

Comment: @BAEE It does work for the sorting part, as you can see here: http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuPk The rest of your question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks, I already found the error with xsltransform.net/jz1PuPk